# Cambiar imagen a un elemento en java

Tags: java

He probado con esto:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("img/Emblem_Silver.png");
        
        switch (tier) {
            case "SILVER":
                   img.setIcon(image);
        }
```

Lo que no se es que ruta tengo que poner en el `new ImageIcon`, adjunto captura del arblol del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yo uso eclipse pero por lo que veo el estilo de la estructura estes utilizando Netbeans, yo lo que haria sería ir a la ruta del proyecto en mi caso por ejemplo sería este:

```
C:\Trabajo\src\workspace\Proyecto\src\main\resources\img
```

Es  muy probable que tu tengas otra ruta pero en la carpeta  `resources` encontraras la carpeta  de  `img`

Comment: Pero no hay forma de poner la ruta del proyecto?

Comment: mira este link te podría ayudar con lo que quieres: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/loading-image-resource/9866659#9866659